# Decode the file to Bitmap in Android throwing exception

Tags: android, image, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

I developed the application to decode a file to Bitmap. I done the following code but it always throwing out of memory exception

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
            Bitmap bmp = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        o.inPurgeable=true;
        //if(!f.exists()) f.createNewFile();

        if(!f.exists()) f.createNewFile();

        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
        try {
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        fis = null;
        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;            
        o2.inPurgeable=true;
        o2.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];

        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
        if (fis != null)
            fis.close();
        fis = null;
        return bmp;
        // return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        System.gc();
        try {
            if (fis != null)
                fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
        fis = null;

    }
          return null;
}
```

Added the log cat

```
12-03 12:03:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(30696): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 12:03:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(30696): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-03 12:03:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(30696):    at  android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
12-03 12:03:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(30696):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:527)
12-03 12:03:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(30696):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:301)
12-03 12:03:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(30696):    at com.dexterity.iPinion.RootActivity.readFromSDCard(RootActivity.java:1984)
12-03 12:03:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(30696):    at com.dexterity.iPinion.RootActivity.setBrandingImage(RootActivity.java:285)
12-03 12:03:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(30696):    at com.dexterity.iPinion.RootActivity.access$0(RootActivity.java:252)
12-03 12:03:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(30696):    at com.dexterity.iPinion.RootActivity$1.handleMessage(RootActivity.java:515)
12-03 12:03:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(30696):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-03 12:03:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(30696):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-03 12:03:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(30696):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-03 12:03:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(30696):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 12:03:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(30696):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-03 12:03:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(30696):    at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-03 12:03:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(30696):    at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-03 12:03:05.070: E/AndroidRuntime(30696):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native   Method)
```

Comment: user4232 edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting BitmapFactory.Options but you are not passing them to your BitmapFactory.decodeStream.

You have:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
```

Should be:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, o2);
```

Also read [Android's displaying bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Also, depending on your device you may have very little runtime memory. This is especially true with older devices being 24MB or less, most newer devices are 64MB or more. You can check with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()
```

In addition you can force a large heap by adding 'android:largeHeap="true" ' to your AndroidManifest.xml file. on my Galaxy Nexus that pushes my heap to 254MB.

Comment: I tried that also not working

Comment: Did you read the documentation link that I provided? It covers things in well.

Comment: Thank you @esse !!! Adding android:largeHeap="true" prevented my app from crashing due to outofmemory exception :)

Answer (score 2):

Android Memory is very low about 14mb

To use bitmap in your app use this link,
official android link to use bitmpas

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html